# Write a tr069 emulate client with perl?

Tags: xml, soap, xml-rpc

I'm a new comer to soap and cwmp, and I want write a fake tr069 client to communicate with acs server(like openACS), I tried SOAP::Lite & XML::Compile::SOAP, but still can not format a right message body for communicating with acs, so any tips and tutorials?
Many thanks!
regards

Comment: you can use existing cwmp client open source like [EasyCwmp](http://www.easycwmp.org). It's a complte cwmp client, stable and fully conform with the TR-069 standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for (no perl implementation)

groovy:
https://github.com/andersnorgaard/groovycpe

Java:
https://github.com/paraam/tr069-simulator

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact problem? You are sending Inform and are not getting InformResponse from ACS? Maybe your Inform message does not meet cwmp scheme - hard to guess.

Comment: I just want to make the test more easy, because a emulator is more easy to control and debug.

Comment: @mkorszun, This one is not an answer, you could have clarified it with a comment right?